# Why does using < and > make no difference to the sort function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to understand how `.sort` works. And so far, the compare function and returns make zero sense.

Here's an array of names in the form `Last Name, First Name`.

```
const people = ['Beck, Glenn', 'Becker, Carl', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beecher, Henry', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter', 'Ben-Gurion, David', 'Benjamin, Walter', 'Benn, Tony', 'Bennington, Chester', 'Benson, Leana', 'Bent, Silas', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Berger, Ric', 'Bergman, Ingmar', 'Berio, Luciano', 'Berle, Milton', 'Berlin, Irving', 'Berne, Eric', 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Berra, Yogi', 'Berry, Halle', 'Berry, Wendell', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Bevan, Aneurin', 'Bevel, Ken', 'Biden, Joseph', 'Bierce, Ambrose', 'Biko, Steve', 'Billings, Josh', 'Biondo, Frank', 'Birrell, Augustine', 'Black, Elk', 'Blair, Robert', 'Blair, Tony', 'Blake, William'];
```

I want to arrange them by last name, low to high.

Here's my code (I'm following [this](https://javascript30.com/) tutorial):

```
  const alpha = people.sort((lastOne, nextOne) => {
    const [aFirst, aLast] = lastOne.split(', ');
    const [bFirst, bLast] = lastOne.split(', ');
    return aLast < bLast ?  1 : -1;
});
```

This obviously works because it's from the tutorial. But I don't understand **why** it works.

- First, these two lines make zero difference in the output - why is that:

  `return aLast < bLast ?  1 : -1;` 
  `return aLast > bLast ?  1 : -1;`
- Second, from the [MDN pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), it says returning a value less than zero will put the first value before the second value. Returning a value greater than zero will put the second value before the first value.

With those two things, I wrote it this way:

`return aLast < bLast ? -1 : 1`: If `a` is smaller than `b`, put `a` first, `b` second (which would be ascending right?). Is this not correct?

But in the tutorial, it's written this way:

`return aLast < bLast ?  1 : -1;`: Which I read as - If `a` is smaller than `b`, return `1`, which would put `b` before `a` (which would be descending right). But this is not what happens in the result. It still arranges from low to high (Or Beck to Blake).

Comment: We need to have  a word with the person who has done the tutorial, as that's the wrong way to sort strings..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `lastOne` for both values (instead of `nextOne`). So

```
const [aFirst, aLast] = lastOne.split(', ');
const [bFirst, bLast] = lastOne.split(', ');
```

should probably be

```
const [aFirst, aLast] = lastOne.split(', ');
const [bFirst, bLast] = nextOne.split(', ');
```